# cartesian product in python multiprocessing with tqdm progress bar

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, progress-bar, cartesian-product, tqdm

I found some code to create a progess bar with tqdm and Python multiprocessing, which uses an integer to update the progress bar. I changed it to use it a file loop, but the lambda callback creates a cartesian product with file paths, which let my machine run out of memory with a great number of files. I tried to find the solution in other questions, but didn't find the answer.
What can I do to avoid the cartesian product in the async_result (and the out of memory), but still create the progress bar?

```
import glob
import jpylyzer
import multiprocessing as mp
from tqdm import tqdm
cores=2
src="/path/to/jp2/files"

def f_process_file(filename):
  now=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  try:
    result = jpylyzer.checkOneFile(filename)
    status=result.findtext('isValid')
  except Exception as ex:
    print("oopsie")
  return filename, status, now

# Find JP2 files in the source directory case insensitively
files = [f for f in glob.iglob(src + '/**/*.[jJ][pP]2', recursive=True)]
filecount=len(files)

# Start a multiprocessing pool
pool =  mp.Pool(processes = cores)

# Define a progress bar
pbar = tqdm(total=filecount)

# process all files asynchronously and do callback for the progress bar
async_result = [pool.map_async(f_process_file, files, callback=lambda _: pbar.update(1)) for file in files]

# magic for the progress barr
results = [p.get() for p in async_result]

pool.close()
pool.join()

for i in range(len(results)):
  if results[i][i][1] != 'True':
    print(results[i][i])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by removing the **[]** from the **async_result**, removing the **callback=lambda** and declaring a global variable **pbar** for the progress bar, before initiating it dynamically

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import glob
from tqdm import tqdm
import time, sys


def f_process_file(filename):
  fnctn=sys._getframe().f_code.co_name
  now=time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
  try:
    # Do some stuff here
    result = 'isValid' # for testing purpose declare a value
    status = 'True' # for testing purpose declare a value
  except Exception as ex:
    print("failure in {}".format(fnctn))

  #update the progress bar
  time.sleep(0.005)
  pbar.update(1)
  return filename, status, now

def f_doall(src):
  files = [f for f in glob.iglob(src + '/**/*.[jJ][pP]2', recursive=True)]
  filecount=len(files)
  print(filecount)
  #Declare a global variable for the progress bar
  global pbar
  # Initiate the progree bar
  pbar  = tqdm(total=filecount)

  for f in files:
    f_process_file(f)

def main():
  src="/path/to/images"
  
  f_doall(src)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Now I can expand my code to use a multi processing pool